# How to save the text filed data automatically in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

There are two text fields in one screen.
After giving the inputs to text filed, with out clicking the done button if you go back to the previous screen and come back to this text filed screen the text got erased!!

can we get this? Please let me know if its possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use any state management tool for instance if you are using React or React Native you can use redux to store the field values and then when you mount the component where your fields are you check if the properties you have in the store have some value then you show those values in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bloc pattern for this,

You'll have a package for this also: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

and you can write your own code also : https://medium.com/codechai/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1

Comment: I think global declaration might b the easiest way for this qst

Comment: for two screens and single value it is the easiest way to declare globally , but handling multiple screens with multiple values it is not a better approach

Comment: Yah,    I think the same

Answer (score 0):

`Declare` your `variable` as `globally` as in the below example or use `sharedprefrence`. If you don't want both you can go for state management [BLOC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc), [PROVIDER](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

```
   String s = "";
   class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoginScreen createState() => _LoginScreen();
    }
    
   class _LoginScreen extends State<LoginScreen> {
     
      @override
      void initState() {    
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildConteTextFormField(
                controller: TextEditingController(
                    text: s),           
         );
      }
    }
```